# Set UIImage with Delegate Method

Tags: ios, uitableview, delegates, uiimage

I've made two delegate for two different classes. One is for a `UITableViewCell` class which is `CameraTapDelegate`.

```
protocol CameraTapDelegate {
    func showCameraOptions()
}
```

Which opens up camera or gallery when user taps a `UIImageView` in Cell. When user selects the image `func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {` is executed. To give this image back to cell I've made another protocol but this time in `ViewController` Class:

```
protocol UserImageDelegate {
    func selectedImage(image: UIImage)
}
```

Which I've called in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` in `ViewController` class to pass the selected image to `UITableViewCell`. So my question is that in `UITableViewCell` class I've added `selectedImage` method but it is not getting executed.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're expecting vs. what is actually happening.  Can you show the code where an object implements the `UserImageDelegate` protocol and how you use that object?

Comment: make sure you also assigned the delegates, and show how you call that `UserImageDelegate`..

Comment: @MilanNosáľ what should I assign `UserImageDelegate` to in `tableViewCell` class?

Comment: @PhillipMills updated my question hope it give a more clear view of the problem now.

Comment: `UserImageDelegate` is implemented by the `UITableViewCell`. The object that knows that an image was selected is `ViewController`. therefore `ViewController` should have somewhere property `weak var userImageDelegate: UserImageDelegate?`. In `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` I would expect to see: `delegate?.selectedImage(image: image)`. Now the only thing that's left is to make sure `delegate` references to the cell, so I guess in `cellForRow` I would expect to see something like: `self.userImageDelegate = cell`

Comment: @MilanNosáľ I followed as you said. I made `var userImageDel: UserImageDelegate?` in `ViewController` and then in `cellForRow` I did `userImageDel = cell` but `func selectedImage(image: UIImage)` is not called. And yes `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` I've `self.delegate?.selectedImage(image: pickedImage)`

Comment: if you set `userImageDel = cell`, then in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` you got to call `self.userImageDel?.selectedImage(image: pickedImage)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162481/discussion-between-milan-nosa-and-chaudhry-talha).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remember to assign a value to the delegate of `UserImageDelegate` type.

`UserImageDelegate` is implemented by the `UITableViewCell`. The object that knows that an image was selected is `ViewController`. Therefore `ViewController` should define property:

```
weak var userImageDelegate: UserImageDelegate?
```

In `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` I would expect to see:

```
userImageDelegate?.selectedImage(image: image)
```

Now the only thing that's left is to make sure the `userImageDelegate` references to the `cell` that implements it, so I guess in `cellForRow` I would expect to see something like:

```
self.userImageDelegate = cell
```